# Shopify Setup for General/Member/Referral Pricing Tier & Referral Link

Tags: shopify, e-commerce, referrals

I'm currently building a referral points system on my Shopify app.

The ideal outcome is for the site to perform the following functions:

1. Show 3 different tiers of pricing - general, referral price, member price (e.g. member can only see member price, those who click the referral link can only see the referral price)
2. Referrer gives the referral link to the referred that contains a discount across the entire shop & discount will only be shown to those who clicked the referral link
3. Assign extra points for products in a specific collection, assign points to referral and assign points to normal members
4. Ensure members cannot assign referral link to another member (only applies to customers that are NOT members, so that members can't send referral links to each other and earn the points)

Could someone recommend an app/several apps that can work together to achieve the above? Currently we're testing with Glow but it seems like there's a limitation - you can send a referral link but clicking the link leads you to the site without being able to showcase the referral pricing (just the general price you've indicated on Shopify for the product)

The link looks something like this https://xxx.myshopify.com/?kb_ref=656990c8a2957

Appreciate your help thanks!